# Не могу запустить webpack в VS code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, сборка

Привет начал изучение React по скаченному курсу Skillbox. В VS code выпадает ошибка при вводе webpack во встроенный терминал. Думаю проблема в том что в моем VS code нет React-dom. Подумал из за этого ошибка, в расширениях React-dom не нашел. Преподаватель все манипуляции делает с webstorm, при этом говоря что то по типу тайпскрипт у вас должен быть установлен глобально, нпм должен установлен глобально. Я скачал расширения для VSCODE следующие: ESLint, HTMLintm, JavaScript (ES6) code snippets, Javascript and TypeScript Nightly, Live Server, npm, Path Intellisense, Prettier - Code formatter, React Native Tools, webpack. Файл Package.json выглядит так:

```
{
  "name": "2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.5",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5",
    "webpack": "^5.49.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "description": ""
}
```

index.jsx выглядит так:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Header } from "./Header";

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    ReactDOM.render(<Header />, document.getElementById('react_root'));
});
```

Header.jsx выглядит так:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export function Header() {
    return (
        <header>
            <h1>Reddit for our own</h1>
        </header>
    );
}
```

В index.html помимо основной разметки div с id react_root.

Ошибка в терминале:

```
asset index.js 106 KiB [compared for emit] (name: main)
modules by path ./node_modules/react/ 94.6 KiB
  ./node_modules/react/index.js 200 bytes [built] [code generated]
  ./node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js 94.4 KiB [built] [code generated]
./src/index.jsx 1.22 KiB [built] [code generated]
./node_modules/object-assign/index.js 2.5 KiB [built] [code generated]

ERROR in ./src/index.jsx 23:28-48
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-dom' in 'K:\work\react\2\src'
resolve 'react-dom' in 'K:\work\react\2\src'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: K:\work\react\2\package.json (relative path: ./src)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      K:\work\react\2\src\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in K:\work\react\2\node_modules
        single file module
          using description file: K:\work\react\2\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/react-dom)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              K:\work\react\2\node_modules\react-dom doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              K:\work\react\2\node_modules\react-dom.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              K:\work\react\2\node_modules\react-dom.json doesn't exist
            .wasm
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              K:\work\react\2\node_modules\react-dom.wasm doesn't exist
        K:\work\react\2\node_modules\react-dom doesn't exist
      looking for modules in K:\work\react\node_modules
        single file module
          No description file found in K:\work\react\node_modules or above
          no extension
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            K:\work\react\node_modules\react-dom doesn't exist
          .js
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            K:\work\react\node_modules\react-dom.js doesn't exist
          .json
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            K:\work\react\node_modules\react-dom.json doesn't exist
          .wasm
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            K:\work\react\node_modules\react-dom.wasm doesn't exist
        K:\work\react\node_modules\react-dom doesn't exist
      K:\work\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      K:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory

ERROR in ./src/index.jsx 24:15-34
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Header' in 'K:\work\react\2\src'
resolve './Header' in 'K:\work\react\2\src'
  using description file: K:\work\react\2\package.json (relative path: ./src)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: K:\work\react\2\package.json (relative path: ./src/Header)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        K:\work\react\2\src\Header doesn't exist
      .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        K:\work\react\2\src\Header.js doesn't exist
      .json
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        K:\work\react\2\src\Header.json doesn't exist
      .wasm
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        K:\work\react\2\src\Header.wasm doesn't exist
      as directory
        K:\work\react\2\src\Header doesn't exist

webpack 5.49.0 compiled with 2 errors in 3377 ms
```

Подскажите в чем проблема, если знаете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед тем как использовать библиотеку react её нужно установить пропиши в терминале

```
npm install react react-dom
```

и в дальнейшем придерживайся этой логики

Comment: спасибо, сам дошел тока что до этого, что может просто установить с нпм. и ошибка ушла!

Comment: есть готовая сборка https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

Comment: я так понял мне подойдет Create React App для фронтенда. спасибо еще раз